# Help with dual-booting Ubuntu

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I was trying to dual-boot with Windows 8 on my Lenovo y-500 recently, but I gave up because there were so many difficulties. Couple hours ago I decided to try again, but I'm running into some difficulties. I received the error:

```
Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error
```

when installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8. I turned my computer off, made sure my secure-boot was off, Legacy support turned on, with priority on UEFI. I retried, but ran into the same error message, so I ran Boot Repair. I came across what appeared to be a concerning error message here:

[image]

I'm a little apprehensive at this step because

1. There were some errors in the terminal and
2. I have no idea what a kernel is and renaming EFI files seems potentially dangerous.

Any help would be enormously appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Hit "No" in the second screenshot, and bootrepair continued. I got this url: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6100240/

EDIT #2: Ran installation again after boot-repair finished, got the same `"Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error"` error message -.-

Comment: Do you have fast startup on (it's on by default), if it is on, see [this link](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/what-is-fast-startup-windows-8-disable-it/) to disable it. Fast startup causes problems

Comment: It seems that you are trying to install Ubuntu in Legacy mode on a HDD with a GPT partition table. This will not work. Either install Ubuntu in UEFI mode (you need the 64 bit version of Ubuntu for this and you need to boot the Ubuntu DVD in UEFI mode) or, if you don't mind erasing your complete hard disk, repartition it with an MBR partition table.

Comment: It looks like you tried to install in BIOS/CSM mode as it created the bios_grub partition. But you also have grub's boot files in UEFI partition. From UEFI menu can you boot ubuntu entry? Also it is an Ultrabook and they have issues with RAID meta-data on drive which interferes with grub2's install. (It does not know it is not really a RAID system.) You do want Ubuntu in UEFI mode. A few system have to install in BIOS mode but then use Boot-Repair to convert to UEFI or convert to UEFI with secure boot.

Comment: It ***is*** possible to install to a GPT disk in BIOS mode, although some buggy BIOSes throw up obstacles that require [jumping through some extra hoops.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html)